# Помогите, почему закрывается cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ("\t\t\t\t'Любимое блюдо'")
#Эта программа считывает по очереди 2 любимых блюда
#пользователя и сцепляет эти 2 строки в одну
print ("\n\t\t\t \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\")
meal_1=input("\tВведите первое любимое блюдо:  ")

meal_2=input("\n\tВведите второе любимое блюдо:  ")

result_meal=meal_1+meal_2
print ("\n\n\tВаше любимое блюдо - " + result_meal)
```

Почему после того, как я ввожу meal_2 и жму Enter, программа закрывается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не запускается Python 3 на Windows 10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055866/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-python-3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-windows-10)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import os
import platform
print ("\t\t\t\t'Любимое блюдо'")
print ("\n\t\t\t \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\")
meal_1=input("\tВведите первое любимое блюдо:  ")

meal_2=input("\n\tВведите второе любимое блюдо:  ")

result_meal=meal_1+meal_2
print ("\n\n\tВаше любимое блюдо - " + result_meal)
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    os.system("pause")

else:
    os.system("read -n 1 -s -r -p 'Press any key to continue'")
```

Comment: Примите ответ если ответ если он вам помог (галочка около ответа)

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk, на самом деле достаточно просто добавить `input()` в конце

Comment: Не-а так лучше :)

Comment: @Victor Во всех ОС есть команда `pause`?

Comment: Ну уж если так , тогда будет работать везде...

Comment: @Victor, мотивируйте, чем именно это лучше? Чтобы просто не дать сразу закрыться программе вы вызываете отдельную программу, причем еще нужно вызывать разные программы в зависимости от системы. И это все вместо одного простого `input()`.

Comment: @Victor Во всех ОС есть команда `read`? Логику уловили?

Comment: @insolor Потому что срабатывает при любой нажатой клавише

Comment: @Михаил Муругов В большинстве систем либо то, либо то :)

Comment: А что вы голосуете против?Kод работает — работает.

Comment: Зачем минусы ставите? Всё же работает, а это один из вариантов :)

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk То, что код работает, не означает, что решение хорошее. Во-первых, в нём нет ответа на вопрос _"Почему программа закрывается?"_, просто выложен какой-то кусок кода без пояснений. Во-вторых, сам код не кроссплатформенный и, IMHO, является огромным костылём, который только запутает того, кто изучает `Python`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("\t\t\t\t'Любимое блюдо'")

#Эта программа считывает по очереди 2 любимых блюда
#пользователя и сцепляет эти 2 строки в одну

print ("\n\t\t\t")

meal_1 = input("\tВведите первое любимое блюдо:  ")
meal_2 = input("\n\tВведите второе любимое блюдо:  ")

result_meal = meal_1 + meal_2

print ("\n\n\tВаше любимое блюдо - " + result_meal)
```

Программа работает. Возможно, вы просто запускаете в `.exe`, и по окончанию программа закрывается. Если так, поставьте в конец пустой `input()`.

Comment: При чём здесь `.exe`?

Comment: Если открытие происходит в `cmd`, в большинстве случаев это значит, что файл был открыт в формате `.exe`.

Comment: @Xij нет, конечно же.