# Не запускается Python 3 на Windows 10

Tags: python

Нажимаю на иконку пайтона,но он просто игнорирует нажатие и не открывается.С главного меню пробовал - то же самое.Пайтон-файлы открываются только на долю секунды и закрываются,хотя они запускались до этого и я в их коде ничего не менял.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь `input()` в конце файла.

Tвоя программа работает так: она выполнилась и завершила свою работу, а так она будет ждать твоего нажатия.

Comment: Можно еще `os.system("pause")`